# Google Maps API - Resizing generates blank white space

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on what it looked to be like a very simple feature which is causing a little bit of a headache.

I work with a GIS and we integrate it with Google Maps. One of the clients requested to be able to open a separate pop up window showing only the map. Opening the window wasn't a problem, but as I try to expand the width of the IFrame which contains the map, in order to fit the window size, the actual map image stays with the same size, and a white space fills the remaining space.

I wonder if I have to pass the new width value to some pre-rendering function or something like that... I've already tried using checkResize() but this proved not to work.

The function I'm using to darw the map IFrame goes below:

```
DrawMapIFrame()
{
   var str = '<iframe id="mapIFrame" name="mapIFrame" width="97%" height="' + parent.mapFrameHeight + '" src="' + $_URL_FleetMonitiorMapIFrame + '?UserID=' + parent.$_UserID + '&Encoding=' + parent.$_Encoding + '&id=' + _id +  '" frameborder="0" scrolling="No"></iframe>';
    document.getElementById("mapIFramePlace").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either you need to expand the div to the size you want *before* creating the map, or you need to use

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

to make the API aware that the size of the container has changed.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up resizing the div before creating the map. Although, understanding the flow was a tricky task =)