# google map displaced and shows only until 50% of the container

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

As I said in title. I dont know why my google map shows only 50% of the container div.

You can see it here:
http://sudarquitectura.com.ar/

please click in the third button which says: "UBICACION".
It is a single and simple html page, so you can see the code there.

It is supossed that the info window should be at the center of the container div but it appears always at the left edge.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First specify a width and a height for you map container div if you don't already in your CSS.
Then try `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')` which is taken from [here](http://code.google.com/intl/el-GR/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) from the events section.

Also check these stack overflow questions

1. [Google Maps API - Resizing generates blank white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437907/google-maps-api-resizing-generates-blank-white-space)
2. [How do I resize a Google Map with JavaScript after it has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743214/how-do-i-resize-a-google-map-with-javascript-after-it-has-loaded)
3. [Google Map shows only partially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358582/google-map-shows-only-partially/4364422#4364422)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! I could fix it following the directions of the third link you sent.

Comment: You are welcome.If you find a useful answer please vote up for it and if you think that your question has been answered please check the right answer tick.